A man rescues a woman from a man with a nail gun
I think this was at the end of the movie. A man enters what seems to be a warehouse. He sees a woman bound to a chair and tries to rescue her. The man with the nail gun appears and tries to kill them but they escape. I think the word "rainbow" was in the title, but I'm not sure. I saw it on TV around 10 years ago. I didn't see the whole thing, only the ending and it just stuck with me.

Anything else to go on?  Year you watched this or year it possibly came out?  Actors/actresses?  Theatrical release or made for tv?

I don't remember. I saw it on tv around 10 years ago. I didn't see the whole thing, only the ending and it just stuck with me.

Pretty sure you're describing a scene near the end of Color of Night from 1994 with Bruce Willis, where the killer is revealed.

A color-blind psychiatrist Bill Capa is stalked by an unknown killer after taking over his murdered friend's therapy group, all of whom have a connection to a mysterious young woman that Capa begins having intense sexual encounters with.

See if the trailer triggers anything:




I've always thought it might be "Color of Night". I'll check out the ending of the movie. Thank you.

Could it be "Pacific Heights" where tennant from hell Michael Keaton tries to kill Melanie Griffifth with a nail gun in the section of her townhouse that is being renovated? Her husband Matthew Modine helps her escape
